# Can I configure custom name for http trigger based azure function of version 2.x runtime?

Tags: azure-functions

My HTTP Trigger azure function is **version 2.x runtime** based.

Is it possible to supply function name via application settings so that it can be changed later as per need?

```
[FunctionName("%FunctionName%")]
       public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
          [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ExecutionContext context)
    {
       //function logic
    }
```

Comment: Some response would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible because attrtibute values always need to be a constant expression. They must be fully evaluated at compile time.

I'm intrigued why you would have this requirement.

Since I always have one function definition per class I do the following:

`[FunctionName(nameof(MyFunction))`]

Where `MyFunction` is the name of the class. More info on function naming in [this blogpost](https://blog.marcduiker.nl/2018/06/21/the-anatomy-of-function-naming.html).

Comment: I know the requirement is weird but that is customer's demand. Now I can go back inform them accordingly.Thanks & appreciate your help.